# Saving MultipleChoiceField in django as a list

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, multiplechoicefield

I have a Django application and want to display multiple choice checkboxes in a user's profile. They will then be able to select multiple items.

I am able save the data in the database, but it is saving like '[u'A', u'B']'.

What should i do to save the selections in a list?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you could be a bit more specific about the issue.

- If you are unable to fetch the values of all the checkboxes and are getting only the last value, you are probably trying to use a get() method instead of a getlist() method. Kind of goes like this:

  ```
  op = request.POST.getlist('MultipleChoiceField')
  ```
- What you are storing currently (as shown in the desc above) is also a list, just that it is a list of unicode strings. If that is the issue, you should do something like this.

  ```
  op = []
  for x in op:
      op.append(str(x))
  ```